# Excel(1) with 10 sheets sorted wrto specific column. Loaded data to excel(2). excel(2) has only 1 sheet which is last sheet of excel(1)

Tags: python, pandas

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("excel_1.xlsx")
sheets = wb.sheet_names()
xl = pd.ExcelFile("excel_1.xlsx")
for sheet in sheets:
    df = xl.parse(sheet)
    df = df.sort_values(by="column2")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("excel_2.xlsx")
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
    writer.save()
```

In excel_2.xlsx i can only find the sorted sheet of the last sheet of excel_1.xlsx.
Please help me in this regard.

Thank You

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create and save the writer outside of the loop.

You're overwriting the file for each sheet now.

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

wb = xlrd.open_workbook("excel_1.xlsx")
xl = pd.ExcelFile("excel_1.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("excel_2.xlsx")
for sheet in wb.sheet_names():
    df = xl.parse(sheet).sort_values(by="column2")
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, index=False)
writer.save()
```